# Как правильно сообщить поисковикам об изменениях на сайте?

Tags: seo, веб-программирование, поисковые-системы

Есть интернет магазин на тысячу товаров. Человек, который занимался им до меня, описания товаров просто скопировал с других сайтов, а некоторые описания вообще отсутствовали и тому подобное.

Я заказал перезапись текстов, их изменили и сделали некоторое изменение дизайна.

Вопрос: Как сообщить об этих изменениях поисковикам? Конкретно интересует Google и Яндекс.

Comment: Как вариант, сгенерировать файл sitemap

Answer (score 1):

Поисковики узнают обо всём сами спустя считанные дни. Примерно раз в полторы-две недели они обновляют свои базы (во всяком случае с Яндексом было так), после чего сайт ранжируется с учётом новой информации.

Если интересуют подробности со стороны поисковика, зарегистрируйте сайт в нём и в разделе для веб-мастеров будете видеть, как поисковик воспринимает его в любой день.

Answer (score 0):

С помощью файла **sitemap** в котором укажите в элементе `<lastmod>2016-08-31</lastmod>` последнюю дату изменения для каждого линка вашего сайт. Например:

`<url>
    <loc>https://example.html</loc>
    <lastmod>2016-08-31</lastmod> 
  </url>`

[*Инфо Гугл*](https://support.google.com/webmasters/topic/4581190?hl=ru).